# создание кнопки в tinymce wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, tinymce

Привет всем. Создал кнопку в  tinymce wordpress: (часть кода)

```
(function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add('mce_button_b', function( editor, url ) {    
            editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+b', "description mce_button_b", function() {
                 editor.focus();
                 var _content = editor.selection.getContent({format : 'raw'});
                 var _parentNode = editor.selection.getSel().focusNode.parentNode;

                 if( _parentNode.className == 'bold' ){
                     editor.selection.select(_parentNode);
                     editor.selection.setContent(_parentNode.innerHTML);
                 }else{
                         editor.selection.setContent('<span class="bold">' + _content + '</span>');
                 }

            });
});
})();
```

Но работает не так как хочется... Когда мы впервые выделяем текст и жмем на нее то текст обрамляется в тег , но когда мы выделяем часть текста который ранее уже обрамлен в тег  и нажимаем на кнопку то со всего текста который обрамлен в тег, он снимается (удаляется тег `<span class="bold">...</span>`)

Все происходит так как и должно быть, как написано в коде, но мне б хотелось изменить поведение при повторном нажатии на уже ранее выделений частичный текст, то есть если у нас ранее выделено `<span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>` и мы повторно выделяем тест ipsum и жмем на кнопку то должно произойти следующее `<span class="bold">Lorem</span> ipsum <span class="bold" >dolor</span >`. Так как происходит с другими стандартными кнопками (например кнопкой italic). Только реализация такого поведения мне пока не понятна. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: В WordPRess есть специальные функции для добавления кнопок, надо пользоваться ими. Посмотрите мой ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710382/wordpress-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/710480#710480

Comment: Стандартная кнопка italic так не работает, как вы пишете, она создает вложенные теги: `<em>Lorem <em>ipsum </em>dolor</em>`